# Can papain or any other protease enzyme from other foods be used to dissolve meat by cooking at appropriate temperatures?

Tags: meat

Papain and other protease enzymes are frequently used to tenderize meat. However, they usually get cooked without a proper temperature control and the optimal protease temperature (which according to [1](https://www.cmbe.engr.uga.edu/bche4510/assign/Handouts/Ch%203%20A3%20papain%20specs%20CBS.pdf) is 55-65 degrees Celsius) is most likely too quickly passed for dissolving meat and only ends up tenderizing it instead. So would an outcome of dissolution of meat be achievable if the ingredients (meat plus papain) are kept at the optimal temperature (55-65 degrees Celsius according to [1](https://www.cmbe.engr.uga.edu/bche4510/assign/Handouts/Ch%203%20A3%20papain%20specs%20CBS.pdf)) for a much longer duration-say, an hour?

Comment: Are you trying to get rid of a body?

Comment: @dbmag9 no, I'm trying to include meat in my diet but since I do not like chewing meat I'm trying to dissolve it before consuming it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the meat that is in direct contact with the enzyme will be dissolved.

This is why the proteases are usually employed in marinating. You can add freshly pressed papaya juice (or kiwi juice, or whichever source you prefer) to your marinade, and let the meat sit in it. When you take it out, the outermost layer will be mushy and will have taken on a very nice taste. Then you fry your steak. The times can be as short as the one hour you mention, but also much longer, for example overnight.

Comment: The outermost layer can get dissolved but what about the inner layers? As in, if kept at higher temperatures for longer durations, can they be dissolved as well? According to [1] in the question, in normal cooking, the protease degrades beyond 65 degrees Celsius so the high protease activity temperature range (55-65 degrees Celsius) only lasts for a short while.